# Typescript: button click not calling function

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm very new to typescript and I've been working on a simple typescript code where on button click, it will display an alert message in the browser. I have tried using button and input tags, and also tried using an onclick event as well as an addEventListener. I'm not quite sure what the issue here is so any help given is highly appreciated.

```js
//typescript portion of code
document.getElementById("disp").addEventListener("click", (evt: Event) => this.disp_alrt());

function disp_alrt(){
    alert("You pressed the button!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" class="button" id="disp" value="Display Alert">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event or alternatively set a callback

```js
//typescript portion of code
document.getElementById("disp").addEventListener("click", Event => this.disp_alrt());

document.getElementById("disp2").addEventListener("click", this.disp_alrt, true);

function disp_alrt(event){
    alert("You pressed the button!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" class="button" id="disp" value="Display Alert">
        <input type="button" class="button" id="disp2" value="Display Alert2">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is not JavaScript, To run typescript you need to transpile it to javascript you can paste your typescript code at playground and get javascript that will execute and understood by browsers. Hope this is clear

I converted your event code `document.getElementById("disp").addEventListener("click", (evt: Event) => this.disp_alrt());` in playground and output was

```
var _this = this;
document.getElementById("disp").addEventListener("click", function (evt) { return _this.disp_alrt(); });
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

```js
//typescript portion of code
//var _this = this;

function disp_alrt(){
    alert("You pressed the button!");
}
document.getElementById("disp").addEventListener("click", function (evt) { return disp_alrt(); });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" class="button" id="disp" value="Display Alert">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please explain why you created a variable?

Comment: @BzeQ you don't need variable if you don't have a context to preserve.. as your event is doing this.disp_alrt you want to make sure context is set properly. Because this.disp_alrt will not work from the event as disp_alrt is not part of this. inside event handler inside event handler this points to target

Comment: it should work as its working here if the code is same

Comment: hmm, well im running it through play framework on intellij, ive installed scala, node.js and typescript on my system, do you think i am missing anything?